# Assigned single Object to multiple script - How many instances

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Have two classes **clsA, clsB** (both are non-static). **clsB** is attached to 20 GameObject while clsA has attached to single GameObject only.
 Now, **clsB** is using **ClsA** as a refrence. I made a public Variable of **clsA** gameObject in **clsB** and now accessing its property in clsB which is attaced 20 Gameobjects(means 20 scripts to 20 gameoBjects).

*My simple 
 Question weather all 20 contains a single **clsA** object or all contain (ClsA) different objects/instances.*

I know the difference between **value type and refrence type** but I am *confuse* at this point cause I am facing some issue then I ask this question well my
 own understanding said that all 20 scripts(**clsB**) have only single instance of clsB. Please clarify ASAP.

As Answer Suggested I wtie this code to get the instance Id. surprisingly it is showing same Instance Id.

```
avgManager = GameObject.Find("AGV Manager").GetComponent<AVGManager>();
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name  + " : " + avgManager.GetInstanceID());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My simple Answer is all 20 contains a single clsA object their is only one instance made and assigned to all 20 objects as I have check by instance id all showing same Id(means instance number).

```
Debug.Log(gameObject.name  + " : " + avgManager.GetInstanceID());
```

**avgManager** is assigned to 20 places and all 20 place showing me the same instance ID. [GetInstanceID](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.GetInstanceID.html) ***Returns the instance id of the object.***

Answer (score 1):

Every clsB will have its own instance of clsA. As there are 20 ClsB there will be 20 clsA object. You can verify this by doing - [Make Object ID](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/03/04/make-object-id/) in the visual studio debugger.

Add the variable to the watch window, rightclick on the variable and select MakeObjectId. Do this again for a different instance of clsB and clsA inside it. If they dont match the same id, you can be sure they are not of the same instance.

Comment: my goodness it means each is a sepereat object of clasA like clsB. I can overcome this problem only if i make clsA static.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan: you don't absolutely need to make clsA static. You could just declare the reference to clsA as static.

Comment: no man its showing the same instanceId. i use this function GetInstanceID().

Comment: Does that mean, there is only one instance of clsA throughout 20 clsB?!

Comment: I might be wrong in my assumptions, I haven't tested what I said. So it might be the case there is only one instance shared among 20 objects. You can check it once again by checking the state of the clsA? if the same state is shared across 20 clsB then you need not worry.